# Ng-repeat doesn't work AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

New at Angular, I spent 2 hours searching my error, helped by a few docs and watching the already existing posts but nothing to do..

I'm just hard declaring an object array and try to loop through it:

Code:

```
angular.module('MyAppModule', [ ])

.controller('GreetsController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
  $scope.name = prompt('What\'s your name ?');
}])

.controller('ListController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
  $scope.personNb = this.persons.length;

  $scope.persons = [
    {
      image: 'images/images(1).jpg',
      name: 'John Doe',
      age: 23
    },
    {
      image: 'images/images.jpg',
      name: 'John Doe',
      age: 23
    },
    {
      image: 'images/téléchargement.jpg',
      name: 'John Doe',
      age: 23
    },
    {
      image: 'images/téléchargement(1).jpg',
      name: 'John Doe',
      age: 23
    }
  ];
}]);
```

---

Html:

```
<div ng-controller="GreetsController">
  <h1>Coding with AngularJs</h1>
  <h2 ng-show="name">{{"Welcome " + name + " !"}}</h2>
</div>

<div ng-controller="ListController" ng-repeat="person in persons">
  <h3>{{person.name}}</h3>
  <h3>{{person.age}}</h3>
</div>

{{ListController.persons[0].age}}
<h3 ng-show="{{ListController.person_nb}}">There is a total of {{ListController.person_nb}} register</h3>
```

I didn't captured it but all the scripts are includes and I add 'MyAppModule' in the depedencies array of app.js

Comment: it's missing your code and html

Comment: what does this.persons refer to? Are there any script errors?

Comment: You have **multiple** issues with your code, really too many to correct in one answer.  I'll try to offer a few here, though;  1. you can't add `ng-controller` and `ng-repeat` on the same element, since that element is the one that is repeated.  2.  you are trying to call `ListController.person_nb` in HTML, which will not work.  3.  your `ng-show` is taking a number and checking true/false for it, which makes no sense.  4.  you try to get a length before you even have an array, and you are trying to get the length of an array on `this`, instead of `$scope`.

Comment: with this many errors, you should take some time to examine the console log in the browser and eliminate the errors individually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had two errors:

1. `<div ng-controller="ListController" ng-repeat="person in persons">` Break the ng-controller and ng-repeat into different elements. You don't want to repeat the controller.
2. `$scope.personNb = this.persons.length;` this.persons does not exist.
3. The summary at the bottom you are trying to access the controller by its class name `ListController`.

See the changes I made. click `Run code snippet` for a demo.

```js
angular.module('MyAppModule', [ ])

.controller('GreetsController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
  $scope.name = "";
  $scope.name = prompt('What\'s your name ?');
}])

.controller('ListController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
  
  $scope.persons = [
    {
      image: 'images/images(1).jpg',
      name: 'John Doe',
      age: 23
    },
    {
      image: 'images/images.jpg',
      name: 'John Doe',
      age: 23
    },
    {
      image: 'images/téléchargement.jpg',
      name: 'John Doe',
      age: 23
    },
    {
      image: 'images/téléchargement(1).jpg',
      name: 'John Doe',
      age: 23
    }
  ];
  
  $scope.personNb = $scope.persons.length;
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="MyAppModule">
<div ng-controller="GreetsController">
  <h1>Coding with AngularJs</h1>
  <h2 ng-show="name">Welcome {{name}}!</h2>
</div>

<div ng-controller="ListController">
  <div ng-repeat="person in persons">
    <h3>{{person.name}}</h3>
    <h3>{{person.age}}</h3>
  </div>
  
  {{persons[0].age}}
<h3 ng-show="{{personNb}}">There is a total of {{personNb}} register</h3>
</div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for all the quick answers, it works now :)

Answer (score 3):

You have 3 mistakes in your **HTML:**

1. You must declare your `ng-app` before calling your controller(s), then put this in one tag above:

So, your **HTML** becomes this:

```
<div ng-app="MyAppModule">
  <div ng-controller="GreetsController">
    <h1>Coding with AngularJs</h1>
    <h2 ng-show="name">{{"Welcome " + name + " !"}}</h2>
  </div>

  <div ng-controller="ListController" ng-repeat="person in persons">
    <h3>{{person.name}}</h3>
    <h3>{{person.age}}</h3>
  </div>

  {{ListController.persons[0].age}}
  <h3 ng-show="{{ListController.person_nb}}">There is a total of {{ListController.person_nb}} register</h3>
</div>
```

2. You must put these lines:

```
{{ListController.persons[0].age}}
<h3 ng-show="{{ListController.person_nb}}">There is a total of {{ListController.person_nb}} register</h3>
```

inside the `<div>` tag that is declared your `ng-controller`.

3. You you should only call this way (without the `ListController`) and also ng-show works **without** interpolation `{{}}`:

```
{{persons[0].age}}
<h3 ng-show="person_nb">There is a total of {{person_nb}} register</h3>
```

I recommend you to take a look on this [tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_00) and follow it step by step.

Also, check this complete demo with your code, made by @Chev:

<kbd>[DEMO](https://codepen.io/Chevex/pen/GqrVYA?editors=1010)</kbd>

Comment: I added it, @Chev.

Comment: Sweet, I was going to make an answer but you covered all the same issues I fixed in the demo before I could post it :)

Comment: It happens a lot with me also :)